# What is the main difference between "Terminalia ivorensis" and "Bucida buceras"?

Tags: species-identification, botany, species

Google images yields photos of similar trees, but they have separate Wikipedia article. I want to know the major difference allowing to identify which is ["*Terminalia ivorensis*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminalia_ivorensis) and ["*Bucida buceras*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucida_buceras).

Comment: I consider it slightly unlikely that one can find images of *Terminalia ivorensis* online. The [African Plant Database](http://www.africanplants.senckenberg.de) (which started out as West African Plant Database, and has a really good coverage in the area) doesn't have contributed images, and this is a West African species.